# Python Tkinter message box add custom image

Tags: python, image, dialog, tkinter

Is there any way to add a custom image to the tkinter built in tkMessageBox?

Comment: Why not just create your own custom message box by subclassing `Toplevel`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not. You'll need to create your own message box with a Toplevel and some widgets. When you do that, you'll have complete control over what goes in the window.